# GeneXus y sus políticas para savepoints y releases a la base de datos

Tags: postgresql, genexus

Tengo un procedimiento en [GeneXus](https://www.genexus.com/en/global/products/genexus) versión 9, que lee valores de la base de datos usando sentencias `FOR EACH`. Esta aplicación en Genexus se ejecuta en PostgreSQL (como base de datos) y VB 6.0 (como lenguaje cliente).

La sentencia es algo parecido a esto:

```
FOR EACH X, Y
   $mycount = &mycount + 1
ENDFOR
```

Así que, como podrán ver, no se hace ninguna escritura a la base de datos.

Este `FOR EACH` está anidado en otro `FOR EACH` de tal forma que, cuando se ejecuta el código, se realizan muchas consultas a la base de datos (una por cada registro en el `FOR EACH` de más afuera).

Inspeccionando el log de PostgreSQL veo que por cada query del `FOR EACH` interno, se ejecutan tres sentencias en la base de datos:

```
# Query #1
statement: SELECT BfOpe2, BFSUCU, BFTIP, BFMONE, BfEmpr, BFOPER, BFAGEN, BFFCHC, AACUEN, BFESTA, bfslec, BFOPE1, BFVEND, BfSup, bfcali, BfCant, bFsOLI, BfInte, BFPRES, BfTCuo, BFFCHV FROM FSD0122 WHERE (AACUEN = '1056476' and BFTIP = 'A') AND (BFAGEN <> 290) AND (BFOPER <> 225) ORDER BY AACUEN, BFTIP, BFFCHV DESC
statement: RELEASE _EXEC_SVP_094EC6A8
statement: SAVEPOINT _EXEC_SVP_094EBFD0
# Query #2
statement: SELECT BfOpe2, BFSUCU, BFTIP, BFMONE, BfEmpr, BFOPER, BFAGEN, BFFCHC, AACUEN, BFESTA, bfslec, BFOPE1, BFVEND, BfSup, bfcali, BfCant, bFsOLI, BfInte, BFPRES, BfTCuo, BFFCHV FROM FSD0122 WHERE (AACUEN = '1056461' and BFTIP = 'A') AND (BFAGEN <> 290) AND (BFOPER <> 225) ORDER BY AACUEN, BFTIP, BFFCHV DESC
statement: RELEASE _EXEC_SVP_094EBFD0
statement: SAVEPOINT _EXEC_SVP_0982F8A0
# Query #3
statement: SELECT BfOpe2, BFSUCU, BFTIP, BFMONE, BfEmpr, BFOPER, BFAGEN, BFFCHC, AACUEN, BFESTA, bfslec, BFOPE1, BFVEND, BfSup, bfcali, BfCant, bFsOLI, BfInte, BFPRES, BfTCuo, BFFCHV FROM FSD0122 WHERE (AACUEN = '1056457' and BFTIP = 'A') AND (BFAGEN <> 290) AND (BFOPER <> 225) ORDER BY AACUEN, BFTIP, BFFCHV DESC
statement: RELEASE _EXEC_SVP_0982F8A0
statement: SAVEPOINT _EXEC_SVP_0982FAE8
```

My procedimiento es extremadamente lento (una de las razones son las ejecuciones innecesarias de estas sentencias `SAVEPOINT` y `RELEASE` ya que no estoy realizando ninguna escritura a la base de datos).

Sé que probablemente el `FOR EACH` anidado no es la mejor estrategia, pero estoy trabajando con código legacy que no escribí (por lo tanto no es sencillo cambiarlo), y, como habrán supuesto por mi pregunta, no tengo expieriencia en GENEXUS.

Mi pregunta: dónde puedo leer documentación sobre la forma en la que GENEXUS interactúa con la base de datos? Qué configuración podría estar causando los `SAVEPOINT` y `RELEASE` innecesarios?

UPDATE: como han pedido, adjunto la porción relevante del código generado:

```
Do While P50532 <> 101
   A85AANOM = RTrim$(B85001AANO)
   A84AACUEN = B84002AACU
   AV80wvuelt = 0
   AV8aacuen = A84AACUEN
   Call GX_CSC01(HConn_Default)
   If Not GX_DB_StmtIsDef(HConn_Default, "P50533", HStmt_P50533) Then

      Gx_err = Gx_odbc_mrc(GX_DB_Declare_StmtEx(HConn_Default, "PTURENOVACI", "P50533", "", GX_CURSOR_TYPE_RE>
      cmdbuf = "SELECT BfOpe2, BFSUCU, BFTIP, BFMONE, BfEmpr, BfSup, BFOPER, BFAGEN, AACUEN, BFESTA,"
      cmdbuf = cmdbuf & " bfslec, BFOPE1, BFVEND, BfCant, BFCAPI, BfInte, BFPRES, BFFCHC, bfcali, BfTCuo,"
      cmdbuf = cmdbuf & " BFFCHV FROM FSD0122 WHERE (AACUEN = ? and BFTIP = 'A') AND (BFAGEN <> 290) AND (BFO>
      cmdbuf = cmdbuf & " <> 225) AND (BfSup <> 59) ORDER BY AACUEN, BFTIP, BFFCHV DESC "
      Gx_err = GX_DB_Set_StmtCmdText(HStmt_P50533, cmdbuf)
      GX_DB_BindColsP50533_01
      GX_DB_BindParmP50533_01
   End If
   Gx_err = GX_DB_SetLong(HStmt_P50533, 1, AV8aacuen, 0)
   Do
      Gx_err = Gx_odbc_mrc_l(GX_DB_StmtFetchFirst(HStmt_P50533), HConn_Default, GX_NOMASK, "PTURENOVACI", CS_>
   Loop While Gx_eop <> 0
   P50533 = Gx_err
   GX_DB_GetP50533_01
   ' acá continua el código....
```

El código fuente de GENEXUS es algo así:

```
Sub 'Posterior'
&wdif = 0
&wdias = 0
For each AACUEN, BFFCHV
    where AACUEN = &aacuen
    WHERE BFFCHV >= &bffchv
    where BFAGEN <> 290  //---TC
    where BFOPER <> 225  //---COMPRA DE CARETRA  04/08/2016
        &wbfoper = BFOPER
        &bfvend  = BFVEND
        &wbfagen = BFAGEN
        &BfSup   = BfSup
        &bfcali  = bfcali
        if (BFESTA <> 13 and  BFESTA <> 15 and BFESTA <> 7)//or (BfSup  = 59) //Si la posterior es cualquier meno>
            For Each CWFILNOM, CQAACUEN, CQFECHA, CQMONE //#02  //CQAACUEN
               where CWFILNOM = 'RENOVAR2'
               where CQAACUEN = &aacuen
               where CQFECHA  = &WFECHA
               where CQMONE   = &tuparid  //Agregado por MMMELGAREJO 07/07/2016
                    delete
            EndFor
            commit.
            exit
        Endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAVEPOINT y RELEASE se generan siempre encerrando una sentencia de actualización (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) en postgresql genexus 9.0.

Por ejemplo:
`SAVEPOINT gxupdate;UPDATE TRN01 SET b1=:b1  WHERE a1 = :a1;RELEASE SAVEPOINT gxupdate`

Pero no se generan para los SELECTS. No veo cómo llegan esos SAVEPOINTS a ejecutarse para esos SELECTS. Si están, parece ser un error.

Si puedes mirar el fuente generado (o enviarlo) ahí se podría ver en qué sentencias SQL se están generando esos SAVEPOINTS.

UPDATE

Fíjate la configuración del driver ODBC, el Level of rollback on errors. Debes de tener el valor Statement que hace que el driver agregue un comando SAVEPOINT al inicio de cada sentencia SQL.

Prueba con el valor Transaction.

https://odbc.postgresql.org/docs/config.html

Comment: Gracias Claudia! Voy a mirar y enviar el código que está generando esos SAVEPOINTs.

Comment: Gracias de vuelta @Claudia. Voy a probar y te cuento luego qué tal.